# Entering and saving XML:literal value into protege

Tags: xml, rdf, owl, semantic-web, protege

I have been trying to assign data type to instance using Data property called asGML ( the instance is an object of the type of  domain class of the  data property ) and the range of the property is data type `rdf:XMLLiteral`. ( please see attached photo named Dataproperty to check the  structure of the data property).

Also, I created an instance called 25484-105 (please check the attached Instance photo )  from the type of  AbstractGeometry class, which is the domain of the data property asGML, and I need to assign the range of the property which is `rdf:MLLiteral`, the value is :

<gml:MultiPolygon><gml:polygonMember><gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>322508.3974999999,183565.0044 322506.8969,183552.0980999999 322509.7991,183506.8011 322527.1961999999,183509.9001999999 322542.4001,183503.7018999999 322553.0031999999,183496.8038999999 322573.3025999999,183471.3011999999 322573.8962,183470.3015 322574.8032,183464.0033 322575.1989,183458.304899999, 322574.3991999999164542.6994999999</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon></gml:polygonMember></gml:MultiPolygon>

The previous value is copied form the Ordnance survey linked data resource as it is and its type is `XMLLiteral`. When [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbnQn.png)ver I assign this value to the created instance, I receive an error ( please refer to attached photo 1 and 2  to see the errors) when I try to save the ontology.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Protege is complaining about the content - it is saying that the content must be well firmed and self contained XML, i.e., an XML parser would be able to parse it by itself. The actual XML isn't visible in the screenshot, can you add it to the question?

Comment: The bit that's visible shows escaped tags (&lt; and similar sequences), that's invalid for this type.

Comment: @Ignazio thank you very much for your comment, I have just edited my questions and I have uploaded some screenshots. could you please see them and help me sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This XML snippet is not self contained because there is no namespace declaration for "gml". It needs to appear on the root element, as it is used there for the first time.

If the declaration for gml exists in the original file but is attached to another node, that's a bug in the original file and should be reported to the authors; if necessary, the declaration can be repeated in the literal, but it must appear there.

Example of accepted literal:

```
<gml:MultiPolygon xmlns:gml="opengis.net/ont/gml#">
    <gml:polygonMember>
        <gml:Polygon>
            <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                <gml:LinearRing>
                    <gml:coordinates>322508.3974999999,183565.0044 322506.8969,183552.0980999999 322509.7991,183506.8011 322527.1961999999,183509.9001999999 322542.4001,183503.7018999999 322553.0031999999,183496.8038999999 322573.3025999999,183471.3011999999 322573.8962,183470.3015 322574.8032,183464.0033 322575.1989,183458.304899999, 322574.3991999999164542.6994999999</gml:coordinates>
                </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
        </gml:Polygon>
    </gml:polygonMember>
</gml:MultiPolygon>
```

The whole ontology file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://test239/xmllit/"
  xml:base="http://test239/xmllit/"
  xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://test239/xmllit"/>
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://test239/xmllit/Test">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#XMLLiteral"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://test239/xmllit/Try">
    <Test rdf:parseType="Literal"><gml:MultiPolygon xmlns:gml="opengis.net/ont/gml#">
<gml:polygonMember>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:outerBoundaryIs>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:coordinates>322508.3974999999,183565.0044 322506.8969,183552.0980999999 322509.7991,183506.8011 322527.1961999999,183509.9001999999 322542.4001,183503.7018999999 322553.0031999999,183496.8038999999 322573.3025999999,183471.3011999999 322573.8962,183470.3015 322574.8032,183464.0033 322575.1989,183458.304899999, 322574.3991999999164542.6994999999</gml:coordinates>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:outerBoundaryIs>
</gml:Polygon>
</gml:polygonMember>
</gml:MultiPolygon></Test>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: thank you very for your response, I have declared xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/ont/gml#" in the active ontology. However, I still have a an error. I tried to repeat the declaration in the literal entering box, but I wouldn't accept it..